# C++ Derived classes and polymorphic dispatching

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Please consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum Type { T1, T2 };

class Base {
   public:
      std::string baseName;
      Type type;

      Base(const std::string& bn, Type t):
         baseName(bn), type(t) {}
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
   public:
      std::string dName;
      int x = 10;

   Derived1(const std::string& bn, const std::string& dn):
      Base(bn, Type::T1), dName("Dervied1"+dn) {}

   int getX(void) const { return x; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
   public:
      std::string dName;
      int y = 20;

   Derived2(const std::string& bn, const std::string& dn):
      Base(bn, Type::T2), dName("Derived2"+dn){}

   int getY(void) const { return y; }
};

void func(Base& b)
{
   if (b.type == Type::T1)
   {
      Derived1& d1 = static_cast<Derived1&>(b);
      std::cout << d1.baseName << " " << d1.dName << " " << d1.getX();
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
      Derived2& d2 = static_cast<Derived2&>(b);
      std::cout << d2.baseName << " " << d2.dName << " " << d2.getY();
   }
};


int main(void)
{
   Derived1 d1("Base", "foo");
   func(d1);
   Derived2 d2("Base", "foo");
   func(d2);
}
```

The requirement is to have a function that can take in the base class value and then depending on the "type" of the derived instance, do something different. My question is - is this the right way of doing things or am I missing some important design pattern. I remember reading that use of static_cast or dynamic_cast means that there is something inherently wrong with the design. I understand that ideally the base class can have virtual functions that the derived classes implement, and at run time they get polymorphically dispatched. However, in this case there are two functions in each derived class that are specific to those classes, viz. getX and getY. How can I change the design to make it better and perhaps not use the cast?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that both getX() and getY() have the same method signature. Do they also have similar functionality? If so, it would be better to (i) give the methods the same name and (ii) make it a virtual method in the base class and have the child classes override it for dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @jithinpt I have cases where they have different functionality and that's what I am wondering about now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The requirement is to have a function that can take in the base class value and then depending on the "type" of the derived instance, do something different.

That is exactly what polymorphism is all about.  But you are not using it the way it is meant to be used.

> My question is - is this the right way of doing things

No.

> am I missing some important design pattern.

This would be better handled by getting rid of `Type` altogether and introduce a virtual method in `Base`.

> I understand that ideally the base class can have virtual functions that the derived classes implement, and at run time they get polymorphically dispatched.

Exactly.

> However, in this case there are two functions in each derived class that are specific to those classes, viz. getX and getY.

So?  Using polymorphism correctly does not prevent that.

> How can I change the design to make it better and perhaps not use the cast?

Use polymorphism correctly. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:
    std::string baseName;

    Base(const std::string& bn):
      baseName(bn) {}

    virtual void doIt() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    std::string dName;
    int x = 10;

    Derived1(const std::string& bn, const std::string& dn):
      Base(bn), dName("Dervied1"+dn) {}

    int getX(void) const { return x; }

    void doIt() override
    {
        std::cout << baseName << " " << dName << " " << getX();
        std::cout << std::endl; 
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    std::string dName;
    int y = 20;

    Derived2(const std::string& bn, const std::string& dn):
      Base(bn), dName("Derived2"+dn) {}

    int getY(void) const { return y; }

    void doIt() override
    {
        std::cout << baseName << " " << dName << " " << getY(); 
    }
};

void func(Base& b)
{
    b.doIt();
}

int main(void)
{
    Derived1 d1("Base", "foo");
    func(d1);
    Derived2 d2("Base", "foo");
    func(d2);
}
```

And then take it a step farther by moving common code around so it can be shared by the derived classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:
    std::string baseName;

    Base(const std::string& bn):
      baseName(bn) {}

    virtual void doIt()
    {
        std::cout << baseName;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    std::string dName;

    Derived(const std::string& bn, const std::string& dn):
      Base(bn), dName(dn) {}

    void doIt() override
    {
        Base::doIt();
        std::cout << " " << dName;
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Derived
{
public:
    int x = 10;

    Derived1(const std::string& bn, const std::string& dn):
      Derived(bn, "Dervied1"+dn) {}

    int getX(void) const { return x; }

    void doIt() override
    {
        Derived::doIt();
        std::cout << " " << getX();
        std::cout << std::endl; 
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Derived
{
public:
    int y = 20;

    Derived2(const std::string& bn, const std::string& dn):
      Derived(bn, "Derived2"+dn) {}

    int getY(void) const { return y; }

    void doIt() override
    {
        Derived::doIt();
        std::cout << " " << getY(); 
    }
};

void func(Base& b)
{
    b.doIt();
}

int main(void)
{
    Derived1 d1("Base", "foo");
    func(d1);
    Derived2 d2("Base", "foo");
    func(d2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally makes sense. An additional question then - how do I handle the case where 'func()' would need access to both 'x' from Derived1 and 'y' from Derived2, and lets assume that 'x' and 'y' are different scalar types, say int and double respectively. In that case a single 'doIt()' returning 'x' or 'y' might not work because they are of different types.

Comment: You would have to either 1) expose virtual `getX` and `getY` methods in the base class that the derived classes can override, or else 2) type-cast (you can use `dynamic_cast` instead of a `Type` enum) the base class to the appropriate derived class when needed. But when you start relying on class-specific values, you defeat the purpose of polymorphism, and should re-evaluate your design.

Comment: Ok, I get the idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option of using a `virtual` member function, as outlined by [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42943788/434551), it is the best approach to use. However, there are situations where you don't have that luxury. In that case, you can build your dispatch mechanism based on the type of the derived type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Base {
   public:
      std::string baseName;

      Base(const std::string& bn): baseName(bn) {}
      virtual ~Base() {}

      // Don't store type ID per instance.
      // Make it a virtual function so derived classes
      // can return the same value for each instance.
      virtual int getTypeID() = 0;

      // Helper function for derived classes to use so each
      // derived class can have a unique type id associated
      // with it. This eliminates the need for having an enum.
      static int getNextTypeID();
      {
         static int typeID = 0;
         return ++typeID;
      }
};


class Derived1 : public Base
{
   public:
      std::string dName;
      int x = 10;

      Derived1(const std::string& bn,
               const std::string& dn):
            Base(bn), dName("Dervied1"+dn) {}

      // get type ID for this class.
      // Every instance of the class will return
      // same value.
      virtual int getTypeID()
      {
         return getTypeIDStatic();
      }

      // This is a crucial piece of function
      // that allows type based dispatch mechanism to work.
      static int getTypeIDStatic()
      {
         static int typeID = Base::getNextTypeID();
         return typeID;
      }

      int getX(void) const { return x; }
};


class Derived2 : public Base
{
   public:
      std::string dName;
      int y = 20;

      Derived2(const std::string& bn,
               const std::string& dn):
            Base(bn), dName("Derived2"+dn){}

      int getY(void) const { return y; }

      virtual int getTypeID()
      {
         return getTypeIDStatic();
      }

      static int getTypeIDStatic()
      {
         static int typeID = Base::getNextTypeID();
         return typeID;
      }
};


// Define a function type.
using Function = void (*)(Base& b);

// Keep a registry of functions that can be called for
// different types derived from Base.
std::map<int, Function>& getRegisteredFunctionsMap()
{
   static std::map<int, Function> functionsMap;
   return functionsMap;
}

// Provide a mechanism to register functions for types
// derived from Base.
template <typename T>
void registerFunction(Function f)
{
   getRegisteredFunctionsMap()[T::getTypeIDStatic()] = f;
}

void func(Base& b)
{
   // Check whether there is a function base on the type of b.
   std::map<int, Function>& functionsMap = getRegisteredFunctionsMap();
   std::map<int, Function>::iterator iter = functionsMap.find(b.getTypeID());
   if ( iter != functionsMap.end() )
   {
      // If yes, call it.
      iter->second(b);
   }
   else
   {
      // No function to deal with the type.
      // Deal with the situation.
   }
};

// A function that can be called when the real type is Derived1.
void derived1Fun(Base& b)
{
   // Assume that b is derived.
   Derived1& d1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1&>(b);

   // Now use d1.
   std::cout << d1.baseName << " " << d1.dName << " " << d1.getX();
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

// A function that can be called when the real type is Derived2.
void derived2Fun(Base& b)
{
   // Assume that b is Derived2.
   Derived2& d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2&>(b);

   // Now use d2.
   std::cout << d2.baseName << " " << d2.dName << " " << d2.getY();
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
   // Register functions for Derived1 and Derived2.
   registerFunction<Derived1>(derived1Fun);
   registerFunction<Derived2>(derived2Fun);

   // Make the function calls.
   Derived1 d1("Base", "foo");
   func(d1);
   Derived2 d2("Base", "foo");
   func(d2);
}
```

Output of running the above program:

```
Base Dervied1foo 10
Base Derived2foo 20
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll have to digest this approach a bit :-)